# Selling US patented product in US from Canada

Tags: patents

If I am selling a product that is patented in the US by US Company and I am selling this product from Canada to both Canadian and US customer. What will be at risk in this case. How can a US company sue a Canadian company if the Canadian company denies the request from US Company to stop selling this product.

Comment: There's also customs enforcement to be aware of.  Shipping the product to the US may be illegal, and depending on what happens there may be criminal penalties involved.  Talk to a lawyer before even trying this.

Answer (score 1):

> How can a US company sue a Canadian company if the Canadian company
>   denies the request from US Company to stop selling this product.

The US company can hire a lawyer and sue you and/or your company in Canadian court. Google "cross-border litigation US canada".